# Disable toolbar or right-click when viewing embedded PDF online - is this possible?

Tags: wordpress, pdf, adobe-reader

I have a WordPress blog that has a hyperlink to a PDF report.  The user clicks the link and the report PDF opens up in another tab.  When it opens up in another tab it uses whatever PDF software is on the local machine (e.g. for me it uses Adobe Reader to view the PDF online).

Is there any way at all that the ability to then select the PDF text, right-click, Copy and then Paste it in to a Word document or such (effectively stealing the information) can be stopped in some way?

On the same page that has the highlighted text mentioned we also have a link to download the entire report which is said PDF.  When this is done, because the PDF was secured in Acrobat before being uploaded to WordPress if someone tries to edit the text then they cannot as the restrictions are in place - but why are the restrictions not in place when the PDF is viewed online?

Any assistance or advice on how to protect the PDF contents when viewed online (I realise it may not even be possible but I am open to suggestions) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by modifying the security properties on the document itself.  I'm not sure if you can do this with Adobe Reader, but I know you *can* do it with Acrobat Pro.  [Here's an article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WSD012A4E1-51D1-4bcd-BA9F-EF03C6F20BB6.html) that describes how to disable copy/paste, printing, etc. etc.  I tested in IE8, FF, and Chrome -- it looks like the permissions are honored.